# Accessing HTML DOM elements from javascript using `.childNodes`

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering about the `.childNodes` property, I have the code below, and for some reason I get 18 children, while 6 are `HTMLInputElement`s as expected, and the rest are `undefined`. What is this about? Is there an efficient way to iterate over the `input` elements?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    window.onload = function(e){
        form = document.getElementById('myForm');
        alert(form.childNodes.length);
        for(i=0; i<form.childNodes.length; i++){
            alert(form[i]);
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id='myForm' action="haha" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" id="fnameAdd" name="name" /><br />
Phone1: <input type="text" id="phone1Add" name="phone1" /><br />
Phone2: <input type="text" id="phone2Add" name="phone2" /><br />
E-Mail: <input type="text" id="emailAdd" name="email" /><br />
Address: <input type="text" id="addressAdd" name="address" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just go to www.jquery.com; they have very good documentation.  Alternatively, if you want a step-by-step tutorial just google "jQuery tutorial"; there are LOTS out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form.elements is the quick way to access every element of a form-

```
window.onload = function(e){
        var s='', form = document.getElementById('myForm'),
        L=form.elements.length;
        s=L+'\n';
        for(var i=0;i<L; i++){
            s+= (form[i].name || form[i].id)+'='+form[i].value+'\n';
        }
        alert(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Text nodes, even if they consist only of whitespace, will also be included in the output, as will the `br` elements.

Use `.children` instead if you want all the elements, including `br`. This will give you element nodes only.  I think older IE incorrectly includes comment nodes, but you have none in your code, so no issue.

Or you could do...

```
form.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

...assuming you only wanted the `input` elements.

And besides that: you forgot to close your `form` element.

Comment: That gives me 11 children (in chrome and IE9)

Comment: @Martin: Refresh your browser to see the most recent updates to my answer.

Comment: Note that `element.children` is not supported by IE versions older than IE9.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: Sure it is. It's supported by (at least) IE5.5 and up.

Comment: Ah, correct. However, in IE8, `element.children` includes comment nodes too, so it's unreliable anyway.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: Yeah, I have that warning in my answer. ;-) It's reliable as long as you keep the comment nodes out.

Answer (score 1):

childNodes also returns text nodes; this is probably the source of your confusion.

To iterate through all the childNodes, but only pay attention to the INPUTs, simply check the node's tagName property.  If the node is a text node it won't have a tagName, and if the node does have a tagName you can check whether tagName == "input".

Comment: Or, as "am not i am" suggested, you can use .children instead, though you'll still need to check .tagName to only get the INPUTs.  Or, as someone commented (not sure who as the comment was deleted) you *could* use jQuery; the jQuery expression $("#myForm INPUT").get() would return just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) to get all form fields, or [`form.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to get `INPUT` elements inside the form.